Add another subquery to one with a pivot
Obviously I need to study a lot more.
Erik Darling helped me with a great query to pull latest backup information (below) and Pivot on full and incremental.  I wanted to add infor4mation if the backup was from native SQL or a 3d party, so in the outer query thought of adding a select to get the "description" from msdb.dbo.backupset but obviously I missed some key point(s) on table querying.
Here is Eric original Query
SELECT
    M.name,
    [Recovery Model] = 
        M.recovery_model_desc,
    [State] = 
        M.state_desc,
    [Last Full Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.D, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [Last Differential Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.I, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        db.name,
        db.state_desc,
        db.recovery_model_desc,
        a.type,
        a.backup_finish_date
    FROM master.sys.databases AS db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
      ON a.database_name = db.name
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(backup_finish_date)
    FOR type IN
    (
        D,
        I
    )
) AS M --ostRecentBackup
WHERE name NOT IN
(
    N'master',
    N'msdb',
    N'model',
    N'tempdb'
);

My additions that fail
SELECT
    M.name,
    [Recovery Model] = 
        M.recovery_model_desc,
    [State] = 
        M.state_desc,
    [Last Full Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.D, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [Last Differential Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.I, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
        (SELECT ( description 
                FROM msdb.dbo.Backupset
                WHERE (a.database_name = db.name) )
FROM
(
    SELECT
        db.name,
        db.state_desc,
        db.recovery_model_desc,
        a.type
        a.backup_finish_date
    FROM master.sys.databases AS db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
      ON a.database_name = db.name
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(backup_finish_date)
    FOR type IN
    (
        D,
        I
    )
) AS M --ostRecentBackup
WHERE name NOT IN
(
    N'master',
    N'msdb',
    N'model',
    N'tempdb'
);


You made quite a mess out of several things, most obviously missing commas (after a.type) and random additional parentheses (like the one before description).
But the bigger problem is that you started inventing aliases (a.database_name = db.name) that don't exist/aren't assigned in the part of the query that they'r being used.
Perhaps the confusion comes from you adding this in:
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
  ON a.database_name = db.name

But assigning an alias here does not carry over to new references to the table elsewhere in the query.
Anyway, this should do it, but the description column is often quite disappointing.
SELECT
    M.name,
    [Recovery Model] = 
        M.recovery_model_desc,
    [State] = 
        M.state_desc,
    [Last Full Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.D, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [Last Differential Backup] = 
        FORMAT(ISNULL(M.I, '19000101'), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'),
    [description] =     
        (
            SELECT 
                b.description
            FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS b
            WHERE M.name = b.database_name 
        )
FROM
(
    SELECT
        db.name,
        db.state_desc,
        db.recovery_model_desc,
        a.type,
        a.backup_finish_date
    FROM master.sys.databases AS db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS a
      ON a.database_name = db.name
) AS Sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(backup_finish_date)
    FOR type IN
    (
        D,
        I
    )
) AS M --ostRecentBackup
WHERE name NOT IN
(
    N'master',
    N'msdb',
    N'model',
    N'tempdb'
);

